# Open local html file in new window

Tags: javascript, html

I have a local html file on my desktop, when i click on it, if I already have chrome open with several tabs open, it will open my local file in the chrome browser in a new tab.

I want it to open in a separate chrome browser window, so its the only webpage open in that window, no other existing tabs should be open.

I also want to resize the window and ive tried something like this in the header of the html file

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var myWindow;
function resizeWinTo() {
    myWindow.resizeTo(600, 600);
    myWindow.focus();
}
window.onload = resizeWinTo;
</script>
```

but it does not work.

How can i do this, open in a new browser window and then resize that window?

EDIT: Just to clarify, I'm clicking in a html file icon on my desktop, not on a link to an html file within some webpage.

EDIT 2: So ive tried doing what some answer has said below, as a test I have created a simple 'hello world' html page called 'myfile.html' which is saved to my desktop, the code for the file is

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>

<script type="text/javascript">
OpenInNewWindow();
var WindowReference;
function OpenInNewWindow()
{
WindowReference = window.open("http://www.google.com",
"DescriptiveWindowName", "resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,status=yes");
}
</script>

</head>

<body>
    <H1> HELLO WORLD! </H1>
</body>

</html>
```

But if I already have my broswer open (my be minimized) with say some pages open, say bbc.com and cnn.com, so I already have two tabs open. When I double click on 'myfile.html' on my desktop, it just opens a third tab in my existing browser.

But I want a completely new separate browser window to open, how can this be done?

Comment: `window.open('http://www.google.com/', 'test', 'toolbars=0,width=400,height=320,left=200,top=200,scrollbars=1,resizable=1');` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open

Comment: where do i put this? and why does it say google.com? i want to open a local html file, say called myfile.html that is on my desktop.

Comment: It says google because I commented before your edits. Opening local files with javascript is a pain. But the path needs to look like this `file:///c:/Users/bean/Desktop/myfile.html`, and you need to launch chrome with specific flags like `--allow-file-access-from-files` which is stupid to begin with because it disables security-features in your browser. Do yourself a favor and set up a local webserver instead.

Comment: If local html/javascript can access your local files then remote html/javascript can access your local files as well. The wall of security is there for a reason. If you need to access local files, maybe you should look into [node.js](https://nodejs.org). Javascript that runs on server (in this case your computer) you can access local files without throwing security out the window and you can open browser windows with [electron](https://www.npmjs.com/package/electron) or similar. Just a thought.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you can do.

Press `win + R` to open Run, enter `regedit` and press enter

```
Go to HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\ChromeHTML\shell\open\command
```

You should see one key, named (Default). Double click this to get an editing pop-up.
Change the key value

From

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" -- "%1"
```

To

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --new-window "%1"
```

Now whenever you open any saved html page you should be able to see in a new window.

[Source](https://superuser.com/questions/166479/force-chrome-to-open-new-pages-in-new-window-not-tab-when-opened-from-a-progr)

Comment: I dont understand? This does not work, ive tried putting the code in the header or in the body of my html file, but it always opens up in the existing browser, not a new one.

Comment: Why is this "http://www.google.com", i dont want to open google.com I want to open the html file that is on my local machine, when i click on this file say its called myfile.html, i want it to open in a completely new browser window, even when I already have a browser window open.

Comment: Thanks, it works, but its not really what I am asking for. I want to click on 'myfile.html' not some other file which then opens 'myfile.html'

Comment: Your problem is not with script this is something about default behavior.i assume that you are using window.you may find edited answer helpful.let me know if it does not.best of luck.